# Android Studio: How to conver ImageBitmap to ImageId?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to display an array of images as bitmap to ListView, can someone help me?

Here is my CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context, String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}
```

}

And here are some code from mainActivity.java

```
ListView list;
ImageView image;
String[] web = {
        "Google Plus",
        "Twitter",
        "Windows",
        "Bing",
        "Itunes",
        "Wordpress",
        "Drupal"
} ;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7

};

CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

all my images are in Bitmap type, I want those to be placed on imageId array to be displayed on Custom ListView

Comment: imageView.setImageBitmap()?? you will have to explain a bit your problem

Comment: @Nanoc I already pasted relevant codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **int[]** array instead of **Integer[]** array,

```
 int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7
```

also make changes accordingly in you **CustomList.java** file

Comment: how to implement ImageBitmap instead of drawable?

Comment: Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

Comment: I mean, how to store Bitmap on array?

Comment: you mau use array of Bitmap[], instead of int[]

Comment: I got it ! Thank you sir :)